# A quicker way of adding 10 for x in range of y lines

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to code a GPA calculator with a GUI for my final project. I coded some of it and got stuck in a part.

```
import  math

x = int(input('How many courses are you taking this year?'))

marklst = []

i = 1

while i <= x:
    y = int(input('What is your mark for this class?'))
    marklst.append(y)
    i += 1

percentage_calculation = sum(marklst)/(x)

print(percentage_calculation)

for percentage_calculation in range(x,y):
    print('Your GPA is 1')

for percentage_calculation in range(w,z):
    print('Your GPA is 2')

for percentage_calculation in range(o,p):
    print('Your GPA is 3')
```

Is there a quicker way of printing your GPA without writing 10 lines of for percentage_calculation in range of (x,y)

Comment: What's the purpose of the loop? Between the rebinding of `percentage_calculation` and the missing variable declarations, this code is quite unclear. Did you mean to use `if` instead of `for`?

Comment: i guess i meant if, if the code runs like that

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just change the `for`s to `if`s it should work fine.

If you are looking for a shorter way of doing it first instead of this part:

```
x = int(input('How many courses are you taking this year?'))

marklst = []

i = 1

while i <= x:
    y = int(input('What is your mark for this class?'))
    marklst.append(y)
    i += 1
```

You can do something like:

```
marklst = input("Please enter your marks for this year seperated by commas:")
# Let's suppose the user entered 5,4,3,5,4 which will give you a string
# Then you can split and cast them to ints
marklst = [int(mark) for mark in marklst.split(",")]

# Your percentage calculation will be 
percentage_calculation = sum(marklst)/(len(marklst))
```

I guess you still have to have the if statements in order to compare and print.